# Select twice from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I have three tables: A, B, C. Table A has a column Description and ID, Table B and C have only ID column, and they are not correlated. I need to join all three tables and I need to get information about description twice; once where table A is joined with table B and one when is joined with table C.

Comment: I would highly recommend you improve your question quality... having so many closed questions will eventually lead to a question ban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT A.Id, A.Description
  FROM A 
  JOIN B ON A.Id = B.Id
 UNION ALL
 SELECT A.Id, A.Description
  FROM A 
  JOIN C ON A.Id = C.Id
```